# d3 scale.linear(): pass data as parameter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I'm building multiple bar charts with d3, and would like to apply the same scale based on the input data, which consists of different JSON arrays, for each chart.
To find the maximum value of each array, I wrote this function:

```
var maxInArray = function (dataArray,propertyName) {
    var result = d3.max(dataArray, function(d) { 
        return +d[propertyName]; 
    });
    return result;
};
```

To find the bar width, I use:

```
var barLength = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxInArray(myArray,"myProperty")])
    .range([0, 400]);
```

Finally, for the chart:

```
d3.select(".mybarchart")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(myArray)
        .enter().append("div")
        .style("width", function(d) { return barLength(d.myProperty) + "px"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.title+" ("+d.propertyName + ")"; });
```

But this approach means barLength still has myArray hard-coded in it.

What I'd rather do is to pass the current value, myArray, and myProperty into a function like this:

```
var barLengthForValue = function (value,dataArray,propertyName) {
    var maxWidth = 400;
    var result = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxInArray(dataArray,propertyName)])
    .range([0, maxWidth]);
    return result;
};
```

To use barLengthForValue for every JSON array I have. But

```
console.log("barLengthForValue: ",barLengthForValue(10,myArray,"myParameter"));
```

Returns

```
function i(n){return o(n)}
```

Presumably because `d3.scale.linear()` can't find the parameter it needs to do the calculation.

I read a lot of tutorials on the matter, but none of them does what I want. They all use d3.scale with a fixed data array.

Is what I am trying possible? Specifically, can I "extend" `d3.scale.linear()` in this fashion?

And a JavaScript question (I guess): How does `d3.scale.linear()` "extract" the parameter 10 here?

```
var scale= d3.scale.linear();
scale(10);
```

Understanding this might help me to understand how to improve `barLengthForValue()`.

Comment: If I understand correctly the only change you need to make is to return `result(value)` instead of `result`.

Comment: That was it. And I understand why, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only change you need to make is to return `result(value)` instead of `result` -- at the moment you're returning the scale object, which needs to be applied to a value to give the mapped value.

Answer (score 2):

You can clean your code up with [`d3.extent()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent). It will find the minimum and maximum values in an array any return it as a handy `[min, max]`. For example:

```
var barLengthForValue = function (value,dataArray,propertyName) {
    var maxWidth = 400;
    var result = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataArray))
    .range([0, maxWidth]);
    return result;
};
```

If you truly want to use max only, you can use[`d3.max()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_max).

You can then set you selection up as a function and redefine the scale's domain as the data changes:

```
function createChart (data) {
  d3.select(".mybarchart")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("div")
        .style("width", function(d) { return barLength(d.myProperty) + "px"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.title+" ("+d.propertyName + ")"; });

  barLength.domain(d3.extent(data))
}

// call createChart for each dataset you want to plot
[ dataSet1, dataSet2, dataSet3 ].map(createChart)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me d3.extent(), I will alter my code accordingly.